# Gulp task fails to write files sporadically

Tags: node.js, gulp

I get the following error, sometimes but not always. And not always that file, it could be any other file, or even a generated `.map` file.

```
[20:39:24] Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open   
 'C:\Projects\SomeWebsite\BuildArtifacts\Styles\Framework\customer-signup.css'
```

The gulp task looks like this:

```
function styles(cb) {
    var stream = require('merge-stream')();

    var styleBundles = bundleConfig.filter(function (bundle) {
        return bundle.type === 'stylesheets';
    });

    styleBundles.forEach((bundle) => {
        let startTime = process.hrtime();

        gutil.log('Starting', gutil.colors.green(bundle.name), 'with', gutil.colors.blue(bundle.files.length), 'files');

        let styleStream = gulp.src(bundle.files, { root: './Website', base: './Website' })
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(less({ compress: false }).on('error', errorHandler))
            .pipe(postcss([
                autoprefixer({
                    browsers: CONFIG.autoprefixer
                })
            ]))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./Website/BuildArtifacts/'))
            .on('error', function(err) {
                gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(err));
                this.emit('end');
            })
            .on('end', function() {
                var duration = process.hrtime(startTime);
                gutil.log('Finished', gutil.colors.green(bundle.name), 'after', gutil.colors.magenta(prettyTime(duration)));
            });

        stream.add(styleStream);
    });

    return stream.isEmpty() ? cb() : stream;
}
```

I'm thinking that it's a problem, where the disk can't write the file that I want to output. But I don't have much to go on, and it also only happens sometimes.

I only tried on Windows 7, with node v6.4.0. But it seems like I'm not the only one with this problem, as other people on the same team sometimes get the same error. It's a gulp 4 script, and it's write a lot of files, think 1000 css files and 1000 .map files.

It's never a file that exist, but only files that I try to write to the disk.

Comment: "it seems like I'm not the only one with this problem" - can you point us to the other examples you found?

Comment: Other people in my team, with the same script but other computers.